# Dumping VTable Offsets on Windows

Tags: c++, debugging

In order to validate a theory I have, I'd like to see (preferably via windbg) a dump of the offsets for a given classes vtable.  For example, given a type I can use "dt Type" to get a dump of the offsets in the type

```
dt CFoo
   +0x000 __VFN_Table : Ptr32
   +0x004 _dwSomething : Int4B
```

I'm looking for something like

```
dvtable CFoo
   +0x000 VirtualFunction1
   +0x004 VirtualFunction2
```

I am also open to external tools that analyze the symbols if necessary

Comment: vtables on windows are actually well described, they follow the COM vtable spec.

Answer (score 4):

Use the "-v" (verbose) option.

```
dt -v CFoo
    +0x000 __VFN_table    Ptr32 to 3 entries
    <function> ~CFoo      void ( void )
    <function> VirtualFunction1      void ( void )
    <function> VirtualFunction2      void ( void )
```

Comment: Thanks but for complex object this makes it hard to see offset.  is there an obvious order ordering I'm missing?  For example, for me this prints some members before it prints the functions    +0x000 __VFN_table : Ptr32 to 7 entries
   +0x004 _aMember      : Ptr32 to class Bar, 23 elements, 0xc bytes
   <function> ...     ..* ( void )

Comment: Could you explain the 'theory' you have, then? Maybe there's another way.

Comment: I'm getting an access violation when doing pFoo->VirtualFunction1(). I'm analyzing a dump, and I see pFoo is non-null, and that the near-null-AV is at 0x00000028.  Dumping pFoo shows that all its memory has been zeroed (including the vtable).  I just want to validate that I know what's going on by verifying that the offset of VirtualFunction1 is 28 which would confirm that the near-null AV comes from vtable+virtualfunction address.